# FCM: How to bring the app from background to foreground?

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an app in which I am using [FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging).](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/tree/master/packages/firebase_messaging)

As given in the README, I've managed to get it all working and the event handlers for `onResume`, `onMessage`, `onLaunch` are all firing properly.

The `onBackgroundMessage` which I think is supposed to run whenever the notifications appear while the app is inactive, needs a top-level dart function.

I need this function to render a particular widget, say, `IncomingCall`. But this being a top-level function, the best I could think of, is to invoke the `main()`:

```
Future<dynamic> myBackgroundMessageHandler(Map<String, dynamic> message) {
  main();
}
```

which then calls `runApp(IncomingCall())` but even this is not working.

So how does one render a widget in Dart when the app is inactive?

Comment: Did you try to change the local variable and redirect the user to a particular widget base on it?